# Downgrading OpenCV-Python to 4.5.4.60 on Windows

Tags: python, opencv, pip, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to downgrade OpenCV-Python from version 4.5.5 to 4.5.4.60.

I am trying to run this example: https://github.com/faustomorales/keras-ocr.
I have seen there are issues with later versions of OpenCV when running this example, so I have tried to downgrade to the recommended version (4.5.4.60). I have tried running the following in a Jupyter Lab terminal:

```
pip install "opencv-python==4.5.4.60" --force-reinstall --user
```

It says that it successfully installs, but when I check my version in Jupyter Notebook, I get the following:

```
import cv2
print(cv2.__version__)
```

Output: 4.5.5

I am fairly new to Windows and Python, so any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling the package? You can do so by `pip uninstall opencv-python`

The other issue maybe, your pip would be installing for pip (python2), while your programme maybe using pip3 (python3). To install using pip3, you can do `pip3 install "opencv-python==4.5.4.60" --force-reinstall --user`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Viv, Thank you so much for your response. I am using python3, so I believe you are right about that being the issue. However, when I try to run the command you provided $pip3 install "opencv-python==4.5.4.60" --force-reinstall --user, it gives me the following error: ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\Users\\Savannah\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Pytho
n39\\site-packages\\~v2\\cv2.cp39-win_amd64.pyd'
Check the permissions. 

However, I checked the permissions and it says full control. Thanks again!

Comment: stop your jupyter. it keeps a handle on some of those files, so they can't be deleted. you are on windows. there is no `pip3` on windows, it's just `pip` there.

Comment: @savannahc are you sure you're looking at the correct folder? pip3 and pip might have different locations.